# should not able to bind list in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
public static List<TemplateInfo> GetTemplateList()
    {
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo("E://DotNetProjects//sftemplating//Templates");
        List<TemplateInfo> lstTemplates = new List<TemplateInfo>();
        foreach (DirectoryInfo temp in dir.GetDirectories())
        {
            TemplateInfo tempObj = new TemplateInfo(temp.Name);
            lstTemplates.Add(tempObj);
        }
        return lstTemplates;
     }
```

and

```
public void BindTemplate()
    {
        ddlTemplateList.DataSource = GetTemplateList();
        ddlTemplateList.DataBind();
    }
```

info is

```
public class TemplateInfo
    {
        public string TemplateName { get; set; }


        public TemplateInfo() { }        

        public TemplateInfo(string TemplateName)
        {
            this.TemplateName = TemplateName;

        }
    }
```

and i call BindTemplate in pageload like this

```
if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindTemplate();
        }
```

but `ddlTemplateList` is bind with  `Templating.TemplateInfo`.Templating is my namespace.Whats my problem.Plz help to find my mistake.

Comment: are you getting error? can you check in debug weather GetTemplateList returns list what you wanted?

Comment: i think you have to set DataValueField & DataTextField for your dropdown list. ddlTemplateList.  ddlTemplateList.DataTextField ="TemplateName";
        ddlTemplateList.DataValueField = "TemplateName";

Comment: @PragneshPatel ya i check in debug.Nothing error.I got a list which i want but ......................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you miss to assgin thie

```
 ddlTemplateList.DataTextField="texttodisplay" ;
 ddlTemplateList.DataValueField="value";
```

You your code will be

```
public void BindTemplate()
{
    ddlTemplateList.DataSource = GetTemplateList();
    ddlTemplateList.DataTextField="texttodisplay" ;
    ddlTemplateList.DataValueField="value";
    ddlTemplateList.DataBind();
}
```